# JAXBException on EAD xsd generation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

1. XSD from there: http://www.loc.gov/ead/ead.xsd
2. JAXB command: xjc ead.xsd -b ead.xjb
3. ead.xjb :
    
   `< bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         version="2.1" >
   < bindings schemaLocation="ead.xsd" version="1.0">
       < bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='title']">
           < bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='type']">
               < property name="TAttribute"/>
           < /bindings>
       < /bindings>
   < /bindings>
   < /bindings>`
4. Exception
    
   `parsing a schema...
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

   with linked exception:
   [com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
   com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter is an interface, and JAXB can't handle interfaces.
   this problem is related to the following location:
           at com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter
           at public com.sun.xml.bind.api.impl.NameConverter com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BIGlobalBinding.nameConverter
           at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BIGlobalBinding
   ]
   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BindInfo.getCustomizationContext(BindInfo.java:356)
   at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.bindinfo.BindInfo.getCustomizationUnmarshaller(BindInfo.java:362)`

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which xjc are you using? 
i will suggest using jdk1.6 inbuilt xjc to generate the needed bindings.

Comment: yes. problem was with java version. using xjc with java 1.7 everything is Ok.